# Why are my point and shoot photos coming out unfocused and blurry?

Tags: film, 35mm, point-and-shoot, blur

I have an Olympus Stylus Zoom 115 DLX camera (point and shoot) and recently got back a roll of film in which nearly every photo was unfocused and blurry. I am not sure why/how this happened. The first 4 photos are perfectly clear, then the rest are blurry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a speculation: it can be film move from the focal plane. Do you see any structural changes in film movement mechanics?

Comment: I don’t think so. Do you mind elaborating on what you mean by that?

Comment: Can you take a photo of camera film compartment?

Comment: @RomeoNinov - I don't really know how these things work - but if the film was not held correctly in position, would the date stamp also not be blurred? If so, that may point to lens damage/misalignment. Motorised bellows not extending correctly.

Comment: @Tetsujin, good point (if the print of date is done via the direction of light to film). And will be good if OP can replace the battery to check it.

Comment: check the area below the viewfinder on the front for finger grease/dirt. Make sure you are not accidentally obscuring the AF sensor when gripping the camera. Happened to a friend once or twice (ok it was me)

Comment: @RomeoNinov I’m in the middle of a roll at the moment, planning to use the rest of it to test focal lengths, then when it’s finished I can take a better look at the inside of the camera. The zoom function of the camera no longer works so that may indicate something is going on. AF sensor malfunction is also a possibility.

Comment: @Yorik Will take a look, thanks!

Comment: @Rhiannon, also check and replace the battery.

Answer (score 6):

Did you cover the autofocus windows somehow accidentally (by your finger)?

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/371815/Olympus-102455-Stylus-Zoom-115-Qd-Dlx-Date-35mm-Camera.html?page=6#manual

Comment: It’s possible, but I would be surprised if I managed to cover it for the entire roll!  The first 4 are clear then the rest of the roll is blurry.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is the autofocus is not working correctly and the camera requires repair.

Yes, the first four pictures were in focus. It probably broke between the fourth and fifth pictures. Maybe just from age and not from anything you did…it is an old camera with plastic parts, old grease, and a low value relative to the cost of professional service.

While it might be possible to repair it, the cost in parts and labor will probably be higher than the cost of replacement. That was might have been true when it was almost new but out of warranty.

Comment: Yes, sadly this may be the case. Thank you.